# NameError: name 'message' is not defined,

Tags: python, nameerror

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
import telebot

owm = OWM('api')
bot = telebot.TeleBot("api", parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather()
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

answer = "In " + message.text + "now " + w.detailed_status() + "\n"
answer += "The temperature is " + str(temp) + "\n\n"

if temp < 10:
    answer = answer + ("it's fucking cold outside, take your coat !")
elif temp < 20:
    answer = answer + ("it's not so cold !")
else:
    answer = answer + ("it's warm outside!")

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

When i launch bot in cmd it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telegrambot.py", line 15, in <module>
    answer = "In " + message.text + "now " + w.detailed_status() + "\n"
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

Comment: Is your line 15 indented properly ? or should it be part of the `send_echo` function ?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_formatter.htm This is code formettor.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vijay said, i think your indention is wrong. "message" is a argument for send_echo function and if you want to use that, you should write your code inside the function.
I think it works:

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
import telebot

owm = OWM('api')
bot = telebot.TeleBot("api")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather()
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

    answer = "In " + message.text + "now " + w.detailed_status() + "\n"
    answer += "The temperature is " + str(temp) + "\n\n"

    if temp < 10:
        answer = answer + ("it's fucking cold outside, take your coat !")
    elif temp < 20:
        answer = answer + ("it's not so cold !")
    else:
        answer = answer + ("it's warm outside!")

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telegrambot.py", line 7, in <module>
    bot = telebot.TeleBot("api", parse_mode=None)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_mode'

Comment: try this: `bot = telebot.TeleBot("api")` (replace line 7)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telegrambot.py", line 9, in <module>
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Comment: Do you installed telebot with pip? `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` or `pip install telebot`?

Comment: second one as i remember

Comment: So, at first, uninstall telebot with `pip uninstall telebot` and then, Install pytelegrambotapi with `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`. After that try to run your code again.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "telegrambot.py", line 7, in <module>
    bot = telebot.TeleBot("api")
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'

Comment: What version of pyTelegramBotAPI you have now? is it 3.7.4? I tested it now and everything was OK, I think problem is inside of your package (maybe it doesn't installed correctly), Or you have one file inside of your code project named "telebot.py" who can make problems.

Comment: 0.3.0 & there is no project named telebot.py

Comment: Update your pyTelegramBotAPI package with `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI --upgrade`

Comment: same probleeeem(

Comment: I don't know is it good idea or not but I think if you uninstall your python completely and then install it again, problem will be fixed. But at first try to uninstall your pyTelegramBotAPI package and install it again for last time. Another way is waiting for professionals to answer here and fix your problem in better way.